# Message node "Log4jLoggingPlugin" cannot be located error is coming in IIB?

Tags: log4j, ibm-mq, esb, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOxAf.png)I have installed log4j plugin Node in IIB server & toolkit. IIB version is 10.0.0.15.   Message node "Log4jLoggingPlugin" cannot be located    Main.msgflow is error is coming. When I delete this errors from toolkit problems window. It is deployed and working fine. when ever i build project again same error message is coming . Kindly guide or  resolve my issue.

[NodeLog4J](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScRdS.png) [error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sX00.png)
I have reinstalled iib toolkit & log4j plugin for iib .

### Message node "Log4jLoggingPlugin" cannot be located  Main.msgflow

Comment: Have you added Log4jLoggingPlugin to your workspace in the Toolkit?

Comment: It has been added to IIB toolkit from install new software

Comment: same post shared in this link also http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=431924&highlight=#431924